# Jquery validation multiple checkbox sets error placement

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have multiple sets of checkboxes.

How can i place the error message to the end of each set of checkboxes.

This code implementation will place the message right after the first element

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xu7ZK/1/)

```
<form id="myForm" action="">

<input type="checkbox" id="check0" name="check0" class="chkgroup"/>
Set 1 check 1?
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" class="chkgroup"/>
Set 1 check 2?
<br />
 <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check2" class="chkgroup"/>
Set 1 check 3?
<br />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="check3" class="chkgroup2"/>
Set 2 check 1?
<br /><input type="checkbox" id="check4" name="check4" class="chkgroup2"/>
Set 2 check 2?
<br /><input type="checkbox" id="check5" name="check5" class="chkgroup2"/>
Set 2 check 3?
<br /><input type="submit" />
```

Custom method is use to validate the checkbox

```
$(function () {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("checkboxCheck", function(value, element,params) {
            return $(params[0]+':checked').length > 0;
    });
    $("#myForm").validate({

        rules: {
            check0:{
                checkboxCheck:['.chkgroup'],
            },
            check3:{
                checkboxCheck:['.chkgroup2'],
            },
        },
        messages: {
            check0:{
                checkboxCheck: "check your checkbox",
            },
            check3:{
                checkboxCheck: "check your checkbox",
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // ajax goes here
            alert("valid form");
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with css `float` and a div wrapper around each set. 
see: http://jsfiddle.net/Xu7ZK/2/

Comment: What if the form contains other element type and the checkbox group is dynamic

Comment: It will still work. The css just alignes the error message to the right top of the wrapper.

Comment: Please see this example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xu7ZK/4/). The message placement seems wrong

Comment: Answers should be self-contained and not rely solely on a jsFiddle link... in this case the jsFiddle demo is broken because the plugin script is giving a 404 error.